# Python - list index out of range in if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a list that usually contains items but is sometimes empty.

Three items from the list are added to the database but I run into errors if it's empty, even though I'm using an `if` statement.

```
if item_list[0]:
    one = item_list[0]
else:
    one = "Unknown"

if item_list[1]:
    two = item_list[1]
else:
    two = "Unknown"

if item_list[2]:
    three = item_list[2]
else:
    three = "Unknown"
```

This still raises the `list index out of range` error if the list is empty. I can't find any other ways in which it could be done, but there must be a better way (I've also read that you should avoid using `else` statements?)

Comment: I'd love to know where you read that you should not use `else` statements. Can you provide a source for that?

Comment: @AustinHastings There was no singular source, just passing comments about it being bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a list is empty, the list has no index; and trying to access an index of the list causes an error.

The error actually occurs in the if statement.

you could obtain the result you expect by doing this:

```
one, two, three = item_list + ["unknown"] * (3 - len(item_list))
```

This line of code creates a temporary list consisting in the concatenation of `item_list` and a list of (3 minus the size of `item_list`) "unknown" strings; which is always a 3-items list. It then [unpacks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) this list in the `one`, `two` and `three` variables

---

details:

- You can multiply a list to obtain a bigger list with duplicate items: `['a', 1, None] * 2` gives `['a', 1, None, 'a', 1, None]`. This is used to create a list of "unknow" strings. Note that multiplying a list by 0 results in an empty list (as expected).
- You can use the addition operator to concatenate 2 (or more) lists: `['a', 'b'] + [1, 2]` gives `['a', 'b', 1, 2]`. This is used to create a 3-items list from `item_list` and the 'unknown' list created by multiplication.
- You can [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) a list in several variable with the assignation operator: `a, b = [1, 2]` gives `a = 1 and b = 2`. It it even possible to use extended unpacking `a, *b = [1, 2, 3]` gives `a = 1 and b = [2, 3]`.

---

example:

```
>>> item_list = [42, 77]
>>> one, two, three = item_list + ["unknown"] * (3 - len(item_list))
>>> one, two, three
(42, 77, 'unknown')
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you have any resources where I could learn about the in-line/compressed style (i.e. `one, two, three = item_list + ["unknown"] * (3 - len(item_list))`). I'm not too sure what you'd call it

Comment: @Sen: I just added details about the used mechanisms but cannot find doc for each. I do not know any resource teaching to write compact code. Keep in mind that compact code is not always a good thing, especially if it make the code difficult to understand. You may want to look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) if you want to learn more useful "tricks" about the language

Comment: Thanks for the super valuable info! I've done the tutorial but I'm still learning :) Sorry if I'm asking to much, but is it possible to use the above (`one, two, three = item_list + ["unknown"] * (3 - len(item_list))`) for lists(?) within lists (so `item_list = [("Get this string", 23), ("Get this string too", 52)]`. If I use `one, two, three = item_list + ["unknown"] * (3 - len(item_list))` in this case it returns `one = ("Get this string", 23)` instead of `one = "Get this string"`

Comment: @Sen: `(str_1, int_1), (str_2, int_2) = item_list`

Answer (score 2):

Python will throw this error if you try to access an element of an array that doesn't exist. So an empty array won't have index 0.

```
if item_list:     # an empty list will be evaluated as False
    one = item_list[0]
else:
    one = "Unknown"

if 1 < len(item_list):
    two = item_list[1]
else:
    two = "Unknown"

if 2 < len(item_list):
    three = item_list[2] 
else:
   three = "Unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

`item_list[1]` will immediately raise an error if there aren't 2 elements in the list; the behavior isn't like that of languages like Clojure, where a null value is instead returned.

Use `len(item_list) > 1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your list is long enough to have a value in the index position you are trying to retrieve from. If you are also trying to avoid using `else` in your condition statement, you can pre-assign your variables with default values.

```python
count = len(item_list)
one, two, three = "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown"
if count > 0:
    one = item_list[0]
if count > 1:
    two = item_list[1]
if count > 2:
    three = item_list[2]
```